# how to vectorize the args of a function in R?

Tags: r, function, loops, vectorization, args

I have a list in R and I'm trying to rename the list members from a character array. For instance:

```
mylist <- list(c('a','b','c'),c('d','e'),'f')
headers <- c('heading1','heading2','heading3')
```

And I can rename the list members like this:

```
names(mylist) <- c(headers[1],
                   headers[2],
                   headers[3])
```

But when my list is 100s of members long, this code is horrible to write. I've tried using a for-loop as well as vectorized notation but nothing works. Apologies for what is doubtless a duplicate question but I've searched a lot of false leads in trying to google it

Comment: `names(mylist) <- headers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the paste function to create numbered headers sequentially in a for loop. Then use the above answer to assign the headers to names of the list.

```
mylist <- list(c('a','b','c'),c('d','e'),'f')
headers <- rep(NA, length(mylist))
for (i in 1:length(mylist)){
  headers[i] <- paste("heading", i, sep = "")
}
names(mylist) <- headers
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `sprintf`-function it is as easy as:

```
names(mylist) <- sprintf("%s%s", "heading", 1:length(mylist))
```

The result:

```
> mylist
$heading1
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$heading2
[1] "d" "e"

$heading3
[1] "f"
```